# iCal not syncing with Google Apps after upgrade to Sierra (10.12.1)

Tags: macos, gmail, ical, google-calendar

I recently upgrade by Macbook to 10.12.1 and I am now getting persistent 403 errors when trying to sync the calendars between Google and iCal.

I have tried removing my Google account re-adding and I get the same error (Attached)

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking on revert to server?

Comment: Yes it just leaves it in the same state